# Angular 4 http CORS No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' with a java servlet

Tags: java, angular, servlets

I'm trying to do a http.post but chrome is showing the following error:

> No Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

My Angular function is:

```
onSubmit(event: Event) {
  event.preventDefault();
    this.leerDatos()
    .subscribe(res => {
      //datos = res.json();
      console.log("Data send");
    }, error => {
          console.log(error.json());
      });



  }

  leerDatos(): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(`http://localhost:8080/LegoRepositoryVincle/CoreServlet`, { name: "bob" }, options)
                    //.map(this.extractData)
                    //.catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

And my servlet doPost method includes:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://localhost:4200");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET,POST");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","X-PINGOTHER, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Cache-Control, Pragma");
```

Comment: That’s likely because your servlet answers POST requests only - but not the pre-flight OPTIONS request that will occur in this situation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: So what i should do?

Comment: Make it handle such pre-flight requests properly, too.

Comment: Finally I moved my angular project into my webcontent and working in the same host works correctly

Comment: I found this solution to avoid CORS between ports http://www.thejavageek.com/2017/06/14/full-stack-application-angular-4-spring-boot/

Answer (score 14):

If you still want to use CORS while developing you can solve this kind of issue using [angular/cli --proxy-config](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md).

Essentially, if you want to make requests to a remote machine having, for example, [nginx](https://nginx.org/en/) web server running, you perform all your calls to your very same application, e.g. `localhost:4200` (default in angular/cli). Then you redirect those responses to your server using `--proxy-config`.

Let's suppose your server's api have all the `/api` prefix entrypoint. You need to create a file called **proxy.config.json** in the root of your project and configure it like:

```
{
    "/api" : {
        "target" : "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx", // Your remote address
        "secure" : false,
        "logLevel" : "debug", // Making Debug Logs in console
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

And then, all your http requests will point to `localhost:4200/api/`.

Finally, you should be done by running `ng server --proxy-config proxy.config.json`.

If you notice that some headers are missing in the request, add them from your web server or edit your `http.service.ts` to append those like in this example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { isNull } from 'lodash';

@Injectable()
export class HttpClientService {

  private _host: string;
  private _authToken: string;
  private _options: RequestOptions = null;

  constructor(private _http: Http, private _config: AppConfig, private _localStorageService: LocalStorageService) {
      this._host = ''; // Your Host here, get it from a configuration file
      this._authToken = ''; // Your token here, get it from API
  }

  /**
   * @returns {RequestOptions}
   */
   createAuthorizationHeader(): RequestOptions {
      // Just checking is this._options is null using lodash
      if (isNull(this._options)) {
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        headers.append('Authorization', this._authToken);
        this._options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
      }
      return this._options;
   }

   /**
    * @param url {string}
    * @param data {Object}
    * @return {Observable<any>}
    */
    get(url?: string, data?: Object): Observable<any> {
      const options = this.createAuthorizationHeader();
      return this._http.get(this._host + url, options);
    }

   /**
    * @param url {string}
    * @param data {Object}
    * @return {Observable<any>}
    */
    post(url?: string, data?: Object): Observable<any> {
      const body = JSON.stringify(data);
      const options = this.createAuthorizationHeader();
      return this._http.post(this._host + url, body, options);
    }

}
```

So, you would perform all of your api calls through this service like

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClientService } from './http.service.ts';

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  _observable: Observable<any> = null;

  constructor(private _http: HttpClientService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this._observable = this _http.get('test/')
                .map((response: Response) => console.log(response.json()));
  }

}
```

**Angular 5 Update**:

In `app.module.ts` now you need to replace `import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';` with `import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';`.

The service changes a bit to:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { isNull, isUndefined } from 'lodash';

@Injectable()
export class HttpClientService {

  private _host: string;
  private _authToken: string;
  private __headers: HttpHeaders;

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient, private _config: AppConfig, private _localStorageService: LocalStorageService) {
      this._host = ''; // Your Host here, get it from a configuration file
      this._authToken = ''; // Your token here, get it from API
  }

  /**
   * @returns {HttpHeaders}
   */
   createAuthorizationHeader(): HttpHeaders {
      // Just checking is this._options is null using lodash
      if (isNull(this.__headers)) {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders()
           .set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
           .set('Authorization', this. _authToken || '');
        this.__headers= new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
      }

      return this.__headers;
   }

   /**
    * @param url {string}
    * @param data {Object}
    * @return {Observable<any>}
    */
    get(url?: string, data?: Object): Observable<any> {
      const options = this.createAuthorizationHeader();
      return this._http.get(this._host + url, {
          headers : this.createAuthorizationHeader()
      });
    }

   /**
    * @param url {string}
    * @param data {Object}
    * @return {Observable<any>}
    */
    post(url?: string, data?: Object): Observable<any> {
      const body = JSON.stringify(data);
      const options = this.createAuthorizationHeader();
      return this._http.post(this._host + url, body, {
          headers : this.createAuthorizationHeader()
      });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use Angular CLI proxy tooling for this purpose.

- 1. you create a file proxy.config.json at the root of your project
- 2. you map your API URLs to target URLs using this syntax

```
 "/api/xxxxxxx" : {
        "target" : "http://www.api.com/xxxxxxx", 
        "secure" : false,
        "logLevel" : "debug",
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
```

- 3. Serve your application using

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json
```