# Post request issue in angular 4

Tags: angular

i have got this issue "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" here is my code

```
 constructor(public http:Http,private baseUrls:BaseUrls) { 

    this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
    this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    this.headers.append('Accept','application/json');
    this.headers.append('content-type','application/json');
    this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });

  }




     getFeaturedDeals()
    {

       return 
       this.http.post(
       'http://localhost:8560/AppApi/Home/FeaturedDeals',
       {
    Index: 0, 
    Count: 4},
    this.options).
       map((res)=>{

    return res.json();
 }) }
```

Comment: see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44925449/angular-4-http-cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-with-a-java-servlet)

Comment: try with jsonp, tutorial [here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/jsonp-with-observables/)

Comment: For back-end what you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

It is the **server** that is responsible for allowing or disallowing requests made by a client (in your case Angular). Hence, the Access-Control-Allow-Origin (and related) headers needs to be set by the server.

Comment: I allow cors in my API (server side) end but still get this error

Comment: @Fatematuzjohura The error message " No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" seems to suggest otherwise. You can inspect your preflight (OPTIONS) request in the network tab in dev tools to make sure it's returning the correct headers.

Comment: Thank you. i solve the issue by allowing AllowAnyMethod = true in server side cors policy

Answer (score 0):

Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a security mechanism that by default blocks requests to another domain. You should set response headers to allow your Angular domain to access to your backend application.

What backend language are you using?

[For .NET you can use this article.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1)